# Having trouble adding selected class to third and second level items in menu

Tags: javascript

can somebody tell me where I am going wrong with this please?

I want to add a 'selected' class to all parent items in a three tier level menu. I can get the first second tier item to add a class to it's parent, but not any of it's equal tier items. I can get the third tier items to add the selected class but not any of their parents.

Below is my code. The best I can do is get SECOND TIER-A and it's parent li item TOP TIER highlighted when li item SECOND TIER-A is selected.

I can get second tier li item SECOND TIER-B to be highlighted but the parent item TOP TIER doesn't get the added class.

I can get the 3rd TIER li items to get the added class but none of the parents.

Any help with this greatly appreciated, I am a bit confused as to what's going on.
Thanks

```
<div class="navBox">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">TOP TIER</a>
            <ul id="subnavlist" class="newWidth">
                <li><a href="#">SECOND TIER-A</a>
                    <ul id="sub-subnavlist">
                        <li><a href="#">3rd TIER</a></li>                                            
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">SECOND TIER-B</a>
                    <ul id="sub-subnavlist" class="navUsed2">                    
                        <li><a href="#">3rd TIER</a></li>                                       
                    </ul>
                </li>                

            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>




$('.navBox li a ').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("selected");         
            $(this).parent().addClass("selected");  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use ***parents("li")*** instead of ***parent()***.

***$(this).parents("li").addClass("selected");***

Comment: Thanks for your input but that hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific, that selects all of the ul li ul li items rather than just the one directly above. And I've tried many modifications but I can't isolate just the immediate parent chain.